# Check page load time in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit, selenium-webdriver

I need to check if the page does not load more than n seconds.

I using C# with Selenium and NUnit

I've seen a few ways:

1:

```cs
var time1=DateTime.Now.Ticks/TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://football.ua");
var time2=DateTime.Now.Ticks / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond;
Console.WriteLine(time2-time1);

//check difference
```

2:

```cs
driver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));          
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(---------);

//If the load is greater than 10 seconds, takes exception
//I doubt this method, since exceptions emerge, even if the place is quite large     timeout (10 sec)
```

3: Using Explicit Waits

Example:

```cs
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.Url = "http://football.ua";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
IWebElement myDynamicElement = wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) =>
    {
    return d.FindElement(By.Id("someDynamicElement"));
    });
```

But I do not know how to anchor waiting to move on url.
Tell me, what is better, or offer their own versions.

Comment: How do you define the page is loaded? `By.Id("someDynamicElement")` exists?

Comment: If you are using Firefox browser, this might be useful - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebug/persist/firebug/m-3liXcd_T4/d-qlcGUHaKIJ

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check that the page does not load for more than N seconds, you should set a pageLoadTimeOut for N seconds while calling the page you're trying to load. This should also be a try/catch block, so you can see when the page has been trying to load for too long. From what I know, if the time out is reached, then the next line of code will continue to execute, so if you don't want code after to execute, the whole block of code should be in a try/catch.